# Android studio freezing after adding dependency in a modular architecture

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to make my project's architecture modular. So whenever I'm going to add an implementation of a new module to an existing Gradle, the Android Studio is going to be frozen by syncing the project. Does anyone have the same issue?
[The time when it gets stuck in a situation to going to be frozen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rFYW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. When you are trying to act with a dynamic module like a library module, it will be frozen. So I used library module for my use case instead.